# Recursion tracing in lisp... could use some advice

Tags: lisp

Could someone spare a moment to help me understand why this keeps evaluating to true throughout this small function in Lisp?

```
(defun fob (n)
   (if (= n 10)
      'true
      (fob (+ n 1))))
```

Keeps evaluating on the trace to:

```
  0: (FOB 5)                                                                                                                                                                                  

    1: (FOB 6)                                                                                                                                                                                

      2: (FOB 7)                                                                                                                                                                              

        3: (FOB 8)                                                                                                                                                                            

          4: (FOB 9)                                                                                                                                                                          

            5: (FOB 10)                                                                                                                                                                       

            5: FOB returned TRUE                                                                                                                                                              

          4: FOB returned TRUE                                                                                                                                                                

        3: FOB returned TRUE                                                                                                                                                                  

      2: FOB returned TRUE                                                                                                                                                                    

    1: FOB returned TRUE                                                                                                                                                                      

  0: FOB returned TRUE
```

I don't understand why it's returning 'true' even though obviously 6 does not equal 10. Am I just reading the trace wrong? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It recurses adding 1 until `n` matches with 10 at which point true is returned back up the recursive calls. Try calling it with something greater than 10 and see what happens.

Comment: So basically I was reading the trace wrong... If I'm understanding you correctly, it's not sending true back up the recursive calls because at each recursive call it evaluated to true, it's only because it did evaluate to true at n = 10 that it's presenting the entirety as true? Also, calling it with a number greater than 10 sends it spiraling out of control as I expected it would. I'm trying to understand recursion and made that very simple function I knew would evaluate to true to help understand what's going on and the output from the trace threw me off.

Comment: Sort of. A call returns true in two cases: (1) `n = 10` inside itself or (2) if `n != 10`, call the function again with `n+1` and return whatever result that is. If some child call returns true (i.e. `n = 10` in some child), the parent function will return true as well.

Comment: Oook... I think I got it now. Thank you very much for your time. It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, recursion has two components: a base case (condition in which no recursive calls are made) and a recursive case. A recursive function whose base case is skipped can return a value via the recursive case.

In your example, adding 1 to `n` per call will arrive at the base case of `n = 10` (assuming `n` started out `<= 10`--if it started out `> 10` you'll have infinite recursion because the base case is unreachable). When a call does reach `n = 10`, the base case will return true which is passed all the way back up the call stack. For your function, there are only two possible outcomes: infinite recursion or returning true.

This explains why all of your functions return true for `n = 5`; although their base cases aren't true until `n = 10`, the result of a child call is.